# How to stop at boot menu for ubuntu miniPC

Tags: boot, password

I had a PC running Ubuntu 12.10. Haven't used it much after installing OS. Now I can't remember the password.

Tried to go to single user mode to reset password, unfortunately, when pressing SHIFT during boot, it doesn't stop at boot menu. I can see the boot menu in a split of second and it disappeared.

This PC doesn't have a USB drive, so it's kind of difficult to run rescue CD.

Any idea how to stop at boot menu so I can go to single user mode?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Speed may be critical. Try holding down the shift key at boot or tapping it repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks you @Elder! It works when I hold down the shift key. I thought pressing it a couple was good enough.

Comment: Posted as an answer please upvote/accept if it worked for you so that others with your problem can find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding down the shift key or tapping it repeatedly so that it is pressed when the system checks it's state.